# Python montage a plot on OpenCV image and record as video

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

Assume that you have a temperature data with sampling rate 512. I want to record this data by synchronized with the camera images. The resulting record going to be just a video file.

I can plot this data with matplotlib and pyqtgraph.

I did it with matplotlib but video sampling rate is decreasing. Here is the code with random incoming data.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # video source: webcam
fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID') # record format xvid
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 1, (800,597)) # output video : output.avi
t = np.arange(0, 512, 1)# sample time axis from 1 to 512

while(cap.isOpened()): # record loop
    ret, frame = cap.read()# get frame from webcam
    if ret==True:
        nse = np.random.randn(len(t))# generate random data squence
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)# subplot random data
        plt.plot(t, nse)
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)# subplot image
        plt.imshow(frame)
        # save matplotlib subplot as last.png
        plt.savefig("last.png")
        plt.clf()
        img=cv2.imread("last.png") # read last.png
        out.write(img) # record last.png image to output.avi 
        cv2.imshow('frame',img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): # exit with press q button in frame window
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release() # relase webcam
out.release() # save video
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # close all windows
```

Comment: maybe disk i/o is slowing down the loop. I do similar stuff but I would not use matplotlib but instead I draw plots directly on the numpy array image data (either zeros or frame) using cv2.line, cv2.polylines etc and then we can send that numpy buffer to cv2.VideoWriter like you are doing.

Comment: can you share opencv draw function which plots form numpy array. I need to see values and the changes. Is the opencv draw functions enough ?

Comment: if you can get the x,y coordinates of all the points (t, nse) then you can use `cv2.polylines` to draw it on numpy array  http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#polylines

Comment: I couldnt understand what is the x,y coordinates? I just want to add the plot to the side or below of image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import cv2

canvas = np.zeros((480,640))

t = np.arange(0, 512, 1) # sample time axis from 1 to 512
nse = np.random.randn(len(t)) 

# some normalization to fit to canvas dimension
t = 640 * t / 512 
nse = 480 * nse / nse.max()

pts = np.vstack((t,nse)).T.astype(np.int)

cv2.polylines(canvas, [pts], False, 255)

imshow(canvas, 'gray')
```

This create the plot in a new zero array (480 x 640). t and nse should be normalized by the canvas dimension as you like.

if your capture frame has 480,640 dimension too, then you can prepare cv2.VideoWriter for 960x640 and concatenate frame and canvas using np.concatenate or np.hstack to have 960x640 array which can be used as the buffer to send to VideoWriter.